# geronimo deploy cli file not found

Tags: deployment, ear, filenotfoundexception, geronimo

Hello I want to deploy an .ear remotely with the deploy.sh of geronimo. But after the upload i get:

```
  http://localhost:8080/remote-deploy/upload
  07:50:22,889 ERROR [DeployTool] Error:
  org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: Unable to deploy   myproj.service.external.ear: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/myproj/geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2/bin/myproj.service.external.ear (No such file or directory)
    /home/myproj/geronimo-tomcat6-javaee5-2.2/bin/myproj.service.external.ear (No such file or directory)

    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.cli.CommandDeploy.runCommand(CommandDeploy.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.cli.CommandDistribute.executeOnline(CommandDistribute.java:149)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.cli.CommandDistribute.execute(CommandDistribute.java:125)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.cli.DeployTool.execute(DeployTool.java:168)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.util.MainConfigurationBootstrapper.main(MainConfigurationBootstrapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.cli.AbstractCLI.executeMain(AbstractCLI.java:65)
    at org.apache.geronimo.cli.deployer.DeployerCLI.main(DeployerCLI.java:31)
```

I'm using geronimo

```
   Version  2.2
   Build    2009.12.07-18:20:06.045-0800
```

My deploy cmd looks like:

```
./deploy.sh  -host hostname --user "usr" --password "pw" deploy myproj.service.external.ear
```

Comment: how about https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-2567

Comment: I had this error before... because i had allowed the port of RMI naming service 1099 but not the port of JMX port 9999 in my firewall rules.